# CSV field import formatting issue

Tags: javascript, python, csv, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to use the heat map visualisation service from Google Maps JavaScript API v3.

I have a csv file with lat, lng and weight. It looks like this:

```
lat,    lng,    weight
37.782551, -122.445368, 1
51.520027,  -0.0923842, 2
```

I wish to get the following result from these csv values-

```
{location: new google.maps.LatLng(37.782551,-122.445368), weight: 1},
{location: new google.maps.LatLng(51.520027,-0.0923842), weight: 2},
```

I have no knowledge of JavaScript, so I tried with Python.

```
with open('./Test.csv', 'rU') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    location = ['{lat},{lng}'.format(**row) for row in reader]
    weight = ['weight'.format(**row) for row in reader]

for i in range(0,(len(location))):
    location_lt = ("new google.mapsLatLng", location[i])
    location_we = (location_lt, "weight", weight)
    print(location_we)
```

However, this has many issues. The weight field is missing. I believe I should try using the zip function. The format is also not as above

```
(('new google.mapsLatLng', '51.5195078,-0.0971911'), 'weight', [])
(('new google.mapsLatLng', '51.520027,-0.0923842'), 'weight', [])
```

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution - it provides a string exactly as you requested -- except the final row has no final comma since it seems that would not be desirable.

Concept similar to the other answer in that you want to transform each row, except I am using string format here directly to produce the result.

```
import csv

class CsvImport():
    resultFormat = "{{location: new google.maps.LatLng({lat},{lng}), weight: {weight}}}"

    def Run(self, filename):
        # Get the formatted rows from CSV file
        rows = self.readCsv(filename)
        print ",\n".join(rows)

    def readCsv(self, fileName):
        with open(fileName, 'rU') as csvfile:
            reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
            # Keys may or may not be pulled in with extra space by DictReader()
            # The next line simply creates a small dict of stripped keys to original padded keys
            keys = { key.strip(): key for (key) in reader.fieldnames }
            # Format each row into the final string
            rows = [ self.makeRow(row, keys) for row in reader ]
            return rows;

    def makeRow(self, row, keys):
        # Account for extra spaces in keys
        return self.resultFormat.format(
            lat=row[keys["lat"]].strip(), 
            lng = row[keys["lng"]].strip(), 
            weight=row[keys["weight"]].strip()
        )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    CsvImport().Run("./Test.csv")
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Great solution and even better explanation, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Let's take seriously that you want a string for the location, as your question says. Then the real underlying issue is simply, how will you transform your CSV file? You will transform each row the same way, so you should create a function for this. For example:

```
import csv

fmt01 = "new google.mapsLatLng({lat},{lng})"
def row_transform01(row):
  lat = row["lat"]
  lng = row["lng"]
  weight = int(row["weight"])
  return dict(location=fmt01.format(lat=lat,lng=lng)
             ,weight=weight
             )

def transform(csvfilename, row_transform):
  with open(csvfilename, 'rU') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    transform = list(row_transform(row) for row in reader)
  return transform

for row in transform("/temp/temp.csv",row_transform01):
  print row
```

**EDIT:**

OK it seems you want `str` where I thought you wanted `dict`.  No sweat, just change the row transform.

```
fmt02 = "{{location: new google.maps.LatLng({lat},{lng}), weight:{weight}}},"
def row_transform02(row):
  lat = row["lat"]
  lng = row["lng"]
  weight = int(row["weight"])
  return fmt02.format(lat=lat,lng=lng, weight=weight)

for row in transform("/temp/temp.csv",row_transform02):
  print row
```

Comment: Thank you @Alan. I have 2 slight issues - I am missing the comma at the end of each record and I there is '' around the 'new google.mapsLatLng

I get {'location': 'new google.mapsLatLng(51.5195078,-0.0971911)', 'weight': 724}

Rather than {location: new google.mapsLatLng(51.5195078,-0.0971911), weight: 724},